# Sending InfluxDB2 Logs to dedicated Logfile

Tags: debian, influxdb

On Debian, my Influxdb2 v2.6 instance runs with systemd and writes the logs to stdout. But I want to send the logs to a dedicated logfile like `/path/to/influxdb.log`.

How can I change this behavior? The [Docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.6/admin/logs/?t=TOML#write-logs-to-a-file) says, I have to change the startup parameter to `influxd 1> /path/to/influxdb.log`. But where is this config located? I assume somewhere inside the `/usr/lib/influxdb/scripts/influxd-systemd-start.sh` file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution!

First, create an empty Logfile with proper Permissions:

```
touch /path/to/influxdb.log
chown influxdb /path/to/influxdb.log
```

Second, modify the the startup script. Inside the file `/usr/lib/influxdb/scripts/influxd-systemd-start.sh` the first line has to change to:

```
/usr/bin/influxd 1> /path/to/influxdb.log &
```

Furthermore, it should be ensured that the following entries are present in `/etc/influxdb/config.toml`:

```
log-level = "info"
```

After restarting the service, the logs are where they should be.